# Setting variables in /etc/environment not having an affect but setting them in command line is

Tags: centos, environment-variables

I am setting certain environment variables for the command `pyspark` to work. When I set the variables in `/etc/environment` and source it, it doesn't work. However, when I set them in command line they do work but ofcourse only for this session. My intent is to set them globally so that even if I re-open the session I can just type `pyspark`

**Setting in /etc/environment**

```
[root@localhost ~]# more /etc/environment
[root@localhost ~]# echo "export SPARK_HOME=/srv/spark" >> /etc/environment
[root@localhost ~]# echo "export PATH="$SPARK_HOME"/bin:"$PATH >> /etc/environment
[root@localhost ~]# echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk" >> /etc/environment
[root@localhost ~]# source /etc/environment
[root@localhost ~]# pyspark --version
-bash: pyspark: command not found
```

**Setting on command line**

```
[root@localhost ~]# export SPARK_HOME=/srv/spark
[root@localhost ~]# export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
[root@localhost ~]# export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk
[root@localhost ~]# pyspark --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Type --help for more information.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put the `export SPARK_HOME=...` etc. commands in the startup files of your shell. With bash, that would be either `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`.

---

On Linux, `/etc/environment` is usually read by `pam_env.so` during login, and it doesn't support expanding existing variables, so setting `PATH=$PATH:/something` will result in the *literal* string `$PATH` to appear in your `PATH`. This isn't what you want. (See e.g. [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fenvironment) and [this](https://superuser.com/a/664236/600133), also for fun [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/389601/etc-environment-export-path).)

Also, setting `PATH` in `/etc/environment` might not work, since the global startup scripts for the shell might rewrite them. (They do on Debian by default, on the old CentOS I have handy, the startup scripts only seem to prepend to `PATH`).

If your system doesn't use `pam_env.so`, but you only source the script by hand, then these considerations don't matter, of course. But it looks like it's widely used by at least a couple of Linux distributions, so it might be a good idea to use another filename.

---

(Because this is completely opposite to what the other answers said, I tested it on an old CentOS.)

I put the following in `/etc/environment`:

```
export FOO1=bar
export FOO2=foo:$FOO
```

After logging in again, `set | grep FOO` shows:

```
FOO1=bar
FOO2='foo:$FOO'
```

Comment: (I didn't have a current CentOS handy to test, so do point me wrong if I am.)

Comment: Nice twist. Shows that knowing a bit can lead to answers, but knowing the full picture will lead to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This line doesn't do what you think:

```
echo "export PATH="$SPARK_HOME"/bin:"$PATH >> /etc/environment
```

The problem is that `$SPARK_HOME` is being evaluated during the `echo` (as is `$PATH`; you probably don't want your *current* PATH in that file).

If you `cat /etc/environment` you'll see the line doesn't look right.

Instead, use

```
echo 'export PATH="$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH"' >> /etc/environment
```

This will use the values of `$SPARK_HOME` and `$PATH` in place when you `source` the file.

Comment: No, your proposal has exactly the same bug as the original. You're writing a shell program to `/etc/environment`, but that's invalid syntax.

Comment: There's two different bugs.  The first bug is that what was being written out to `/etc/environment` was being evaluated at the wrong point.  That's what I fixed.  With that fix the OP can `source` the file as per his example and it'll work.   There's a second _logical_ bug if he wants that file to be used in pam_env in that `$VAR` syntax isn't understood.